# Why doesn't xenodm starts the X Window System by default in OpenBSD?

Tags: x11, openbsd

During OpenBSD 6.2 install:

```
Do you want the X Windows System to be started by xenodm(1) [no]?
```

And the default answer is "no". Why does it brings it up, if the default is no?

**The question**: But why isn't it "yes" by default? Are there any "better" handlers that start the "GUI"?

Comment: because some folks instead like to type `startx` when they want some X11

Comment: Maybe OpenBSD tends to be used more in server-type roles that don’t require X Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Because the less you let the system 'automagically' do things for you by means of scripts you haven't created, the more you have to learn how your system work (which is good).
You can learn how to configure xenodm and start x by reading the FAQ : [The X Window System | OpenBSD](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq11.html#StartingX)